# Django: Time zone is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am passing the timezone like GMT +4:30

this is the way i am serializing the dict

```
json = {}


json['timezone'] = form.cleaned_data['timezone']
from django.utils import simplejson
getjson  = simplejson.dumps(json)
```

and i am getting

```
<GlobalVariable: GMT +4.30> is not JSON serializable
```

How do I serialize it, any idea ....?

make sure in forms.py i am defining my timezone field like

```
timezone = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Status", queryset=GlobalVariable.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'selector'}))
```

Comment: Seems that your code is working well, tested with django 1.2.5 and python 2.7

Comment: i am using django 1.4 and python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from django.utils import simplejson
>>> from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
>>> a = simplejson.dumps(json, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
>>> a
'{"timezone": "GMT + 4.30"}'
```

Comment: i already tried this but same error print json['timezone'] is printing  GMT +4.30

Comment: if i am using json['timezone'] = 'GMT +4.30' its working fine but for  json['timezone'] = form.cleaned_data['timezone'] it is not working

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to rename your var :

```
timezone = {'timezone': 'GMT +4:30'}
getjson  = simplejson.dumps(timezone)
```

I haven't tried using Django but with the json module of Python there is no problem.